# How to add a additional menu beside a select option? (react)

Tags: html, reactjs, react-select

I found a greate select lib for react (react-select), but it not supported for nested select options, so I want to know how to add an additional menu beside a select option? it's kind of like the bookmark collection.
[image]
here I have a demo :
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hzgaed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution , antd - cascader menu. it 100% matched my reuirment.
here is the link : https://ant.design/components/cascader/

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-metismenu, this library is for infinite nested options.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's great lib. but what I need is to display the menu beside a option.do you know how to do it in a existing select option?

Comment: can you describe more, what you want to do?

Comment: react-metismenu only supported show sub menu in vertical direction, what I need is to display the sub menu beside the main menu.the UI should like the picture I posted in the question.

Comment: you can override the css classes of react-metismenu, and change the design as you want.